# Problem with convert URLSearchParams to valid object

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

I need convert query string `location[okrug][]=38&location[okrug][]=41` to object.

```js
for (let [key, val] of new URLSearchParams(location.search)) {
    console.log(key) //got location except of location[okrug][]
    console.log(val) //got [object Object] except of [38, 41]
}
```

My bad. I passing to URLSearchParams object like this:

```
let filter = {
    location: {
        okrug: [38, 41]
    }
}

for (let [key, val] of new URLSearchParams(filter)) {
    console.log(key) //got location except of location[okrug][]
    console.log(val) //got [object Object] except of [38, 41]
}
```

In this case i need to convert object to query string and pass into constructor URLSearchParams? Then i got wrong string:

```
let filter = {
    location: {
        okrug: [38, 41]
    }
}

console.log(new URLSearchParams(filter).toString()) //got location=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

Comment: Change `UrlSearchParams` to `URLSearchParams` and try again. also try console.log(JSON.stringify(val))

Comment: Same... https://skr.sh/sGdRyUMI5vA

Comment: what is the content of location object? console.log(location)

Comment: Are you trying to convert **filter** into a query string?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I passing to `URLSearchParams` object like this:

```js
let filter = {
    location: {
        okrug: [38, 41]
    }
}

for (let [key, val] of new URLSearchParams(filter)) {
    console.log(key) //got location except of location[okrug][]
    console.log(val) //got [object Object] except of [38, 41]
}
```

In this case i need to convert object to query string and pass into constructor `URLSearchParams`? Then i got wrong string:

```js
let filter = {
    location: {
        okrug: [38, 41]
    }
}

console.log(new URLSearchParams(filter).toString()) //got location=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

https://skr.sh/sGd4pg5KyaY

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid :)
I am again was wrong.
I just need to right inicialize filter:

```js
let filter = this.pageFilter || new URLSearchParams(location.search)
```

Thanks to all :D